# How to use vim to open files that begin with a plus sign (for example +foo.out)?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim

In my file system, I have some files which start with a plus sign. When I try to open these with vim an error is thrown.

For example, when typing...

```
vim +foo.out
```

I get the following error...

```
Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: foo.out
```

I can see that vim thinks that since there is a plus sign, I must be trying to run some kind of command, but since it's followed by a filename it doesn't know what to do. Any suggestions on how I get around this and open/edit the files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `vim` does not interpret `+foo.out` as a filename. There are at least two solutions:

1. Make the argument look like an absolute or [relative path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397524/108618), so it doesn't start with `+` or `-`. In this case

   ```
   vim ./+foo.out
   ```

   In general this is useful when the argument is a filename. If it's not (e.g. `grep -string-to-find`) then you need to use another method.
2. Inform the tool when it should stop parsing options. A common way is to use a [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618). In this case it will be

   ```
   vim -- +foo.out
   ```

   In general this is useful when the tool supports this meaning of `--`. Vim does, many tools do (note: supporting `--` is one of the [POSIX guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)); but some don't.

If each method can be used then using them both is kinda excessive but by no means an error:

```
vim -- ./+foo.out
```